# swift unit test if a function was called

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I am still learning swift and so this might be a very very basic question.
I have this function in my view controller -

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  fetchData()
}
```

I am trying to test if the *fetchData* function is called, when the viewDidLoad is called. In Objective C, I used to be able to use OCMock and expect if that method was called.
Would anyone be able to help me with how I can do test this in swift?

Comment: Unit test should describe functional behaviour of your code, not implementation details. Seeing if fetchData() is called is actually a red herring. What you should test instead is that a loaded view has some data or whatever

Comment: "I am trying to test if the fetchData function is called when the viewDidLoad is called" You know that it is called there. You are calling it there.

Comment: init your view controller in unittest case, call `loadViewIfNeeded()` then pray